# Modeling Fact Tables that have direct relationships, but at a detail and not a dimension layer

Tags: sql-server, ssas, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, cube

This is very similar to my issue.
http://forum.kimballgroup.com/t2534-modeling-fact-tables-that-have-direct-relationships-but-at-a-detail-and-not-a-dimension-layer

I’ve got a fact table for POs, Supplier Invoices, Payments, Receipts, etc. They have some dimensions in common, others not. Problem is, for example, say if they are looking at invoices by their gl account, (using an excel pivot table connected to the cube) then they expect to be able drop in a column for the PO number, the buyer of the PO, etc. Even though the buyer dimension is only related to the PO, and the account dimension is only related to the invoice. But they say, well the PO is related to the invoice, so you should be able to pull it in.

I do have a PO Ref field on the invoice fact table, but it is only filled out 50% of the time. Even when it is, you could have a one to many relationship in either way between a PO and an invoice, as far as I understand it at least. 
Anyway, they expect to be able to throw in any measure from any measure group, and every single possible dimension to work, and then be able to drill down to the detail to see the POs, Invoices, Payments and Receipts and how they match up. Best practice is to keep the fact tables separate if they are different grains according to Kimball, but then all the business problems aren't solved this way.

The only solutions I can come up with are:

1. to either tack on a bunch of detail related columns to the degenerate dimensions when I load them. i.e. add PO to invoice and invoice to PO etc., but have it as a comma separated list in that column when it is many to one.
2. Create every possible relationship with every fact and dimension table. This would be a lot of work though, and some still may not have a relationship to certain dimensions.
3. Create a monstrous fact table with all the current ones joined together, and somehow figure out logic to only display the measure  values once for the many to one joins.
4. This is probably a bad idea, but thought maybe somehow I could create a relationship between every measure group and the corresponding degenerate dimensions reference field. Like create a relationship between the supplier invoice degenerate dimension PO Ref field and the purchase order line measure group PO field.
5. Lower their expectations, lol.

Here's a screen shot of the dimension usage tab to give an idea of what it looks like currently.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried option 3 once.  The performance was terrible.  The output was misleading.  Never ever again.

Your best bet is to work with the business.  Where the data is not readily available (invoice without PO, for example) agree what should be done.  You could show a default value (*PO not recorded on invoice*).  You could agree on a logic, implemented in the ETL, that extracts the most likely PO.

Whatever approach you choose you must discuss it.  If you do not the business will make decisions based on false assumptions.  The business will find itself looking at reporting it does not understand.  You must help your users to avoid these outcomes.

Once the approach has been agreed, document it.  When queries arise, share the documentation.  Make sure the documentation highlights all calculations, difficulties and missing source data.

Work with the teams that generate your source date.  If an important field is sparsely populated arrange a meeting.  See if the capture processes can be improved.  Let your users know that you are investigating this area.  Keep them informed of the outcome.  If the source data cannot be improved (invoices continue to be raised without a PO), inform your users of the reasons for this.

Managing your customers can be challenging.  Especially those who hold senior positions in the company.  Transparency and solid documentation will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Helps to know to not go with option 3. I came to a similar conclusion about getting the business to document all the relationships. I am going to do a bus matrix, have the business fill it out, and use it create as many of the missing dimension and fact relationships as possible. Have the BA's write up technically how each of those relate. So, option 2 basically. A lot of work, but it will solve quite a bit.  After that's done, if they still aren't satisfied, maybe figure out some many to many relationships at the detail level with bridge tables. Hopefully not though.